# mongo client: how can I reuse the client in separate file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-nodejs-driver

Here is db.js file

```
const client = new MongoClient(DATABASE, mongodbOptions);

const connectWithMongoDb = () => {
  client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log('db connected');
    }
  });
};

module.exports = { client, connectWithMongoDb };
```

I called the connectWithMongoDb function from my server.js. db connects successfully. but the problem is I can't reuse the `client`. for example, I want to make a separate directory for collections. (in order to get a collection I need `client` object)

So, here is my collection.js file

```
const { client } = require('../helpers/db-helper/db');

exports.collection = client.db('organicdb').collection('products');
```

but the problem arises as soon as this file(collection.js) is called.

I am getting this error:

```
throw new MongoError('MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the connection after connecting to MongoDB post that you can use it anywhere.

Read - https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html

```
let client;

async function connect() {
    if (!client) {
        client = await MongoClient.connect(DATABASE, mongodbOptions)
        .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
    }
    return client;
}

conet getConectedClient = () => client;  

const testConnection = connect()
    .then((connection) => console.log(connection)); // call the function like this


module.exports = { connect, getConectedClient };
```

Comment: after applying your code. 
I can't use `mongoClient.db`

i am getting `can't read property db of null`

Comment: well. now when I call the connectWithMongo(client) from another file. I am getting
`TypeError: client.connect is not a function`

Comment: you can check this: https://i.postimg.cc/wT3kGY9P/carbon.png

Comment: @Ashik Check now, `const testConnection = getClient()
    .then((connection) => console.log(connection));`  connection variable inside then block is the db connection.

Comment: so , I have to call `getClient` on those files where I need client?

Comment: yes, @Ashik   ```getClient()
    .then((client) => {
     console.log(client) // here is your db client
    });```

Comment: @Ashik You can getClient() on app.start and other files you can use `getConectedClient()` to get db access without then block.

Comment: you mean connect() on app.start and getConnectedClinet() on other files?
I tried that.  ```const client = getConectedClient();
  const collection = client.db('organicdb').collection('products');``` but the problem is I am getting `can not read db of undefined`

Comment: @Ashik in that case use `connect()     .then((connection) => {  console.log(connection); const collection = connection.db('organicdb').collection('products');     });`

Comment: this is my repo.
https://github.com/ashiqdev/mongo-client-boilerplate

Comment: the only solution so for I got is create new client on each request. which is not good at all
https://github.com/ashiqdev/mongo-client-boilerplate/blob/main/models/Collection.js

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/ashiqdev/mongo-client-boilerplate/pull/1/commits/962c5ce5638718a48c1eb6d49cb7bef552534c32